# Wilcoxon test on a large dataset algorithm

Tags: r, dataset, comparison

I have a large dataset: each row is a sample and each column is a feature. The first column however is filled with class factors (which here is 1,2,3,4,5). My aim is to do a wilcoxon comparison between all the classes (so for every combination 1,2:1,3;1,4;1,5;2,3...) for all the features. This is the code I wrote in order to do this (X is the dataframe)

```
facs <- length(levels(factor(X[,1])))

v <- matrix(as.character(combn(facs,2)),ncol=facs*2)

vecBoh <- data.frame(row.names=paste(v[1,],"-",v[2,]))

for(i in 2:ncol(X))
{
     WilF <- function(coppie)  wilcox.test(X[,i] ~ Class, data=X, subset = Class %in% coppie)

     vecBoh[,i-1] <- as.numeric(sapply(apply(v,2,WilF),"[",3))
}
```

It works but it's extremely slow. I have the feeling there's a quicker way to do this. Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: What is the smallest number of observations in a group?

Comment: every sample is composed by 4273 observations (features) but there are missing values in the dataset.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider a parametric test to speed it up.  At that amount of data, the CLT takes over.

Comment: The data are not normally distributed. That's why I have to use non-parametric methods.

Comment: If you are testing location (i.e. mean), the data itself does not have to be normal for the mean to be normal.  The latter is all that is needed for the t-test ([referance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Assumptions)).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `pairwise.wilcox.test` function for pairwise comparison between groups and I think that reading about [multiple comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem) before can help here.

```
lapply(df[,-1], function(x) 
                  pairwise.wilcox.test(x, df$Class, p.adjust.method = "none"))
```

Where `df` is your `data.frame`